# handle error in gulp with plumber and utils

Tags: gulp-uglify

using gulp with plumber module but stuck into the problem; below is my main gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require("gulp-load-plugins")({
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', 'browserify**'],
  replaceString: /\bgulp[\-.]/
});

var src = './app/';
var dest = './env/';

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    return gulp.src([src + '**/*.js'])
            .pipe($.plumber(function(error) {
                  // Output an error message
                  $.util.log($.util.colors.red('Error (' + error.plugin + '): ' + error.message));
                  // emit the end event, to properly end the task
                  this.emit('end');
             }))
            .pipe($.uglify().on('error', $.util.log))
            .pipe($.concat('vendor.min.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

running `gulp scripts` gives error two times [image: see] as there is `$.plumber()` and `$.uglify().on` method; I want to show into one, so that error comes in handy way with red color in console. If i emit `.on('error', $.util.log)` than execution stops and crash the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's like magic; most of the times whenever I ask questions on SO , I found the solution by myself within few trials.

tried this and succeed

```
var onError = function (err) {
    $.util.log($.util.colors.red('Error (' + err.plugin + '): ' + err.message));
};
```

and later

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
        return gulp.src([src + '**/*.js'])
                .pipe($.plumber())
                .pipe($.uglify().on('error', onError))
                .pipe($.plumber.stop())
                .pipe($.concat('vendor.min.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

hope it helps someone